# api Тестинг на Phpunit

Tags: юнит-тесты, phpunit

Как можно в `assertContains` задать 2 значение. Например. у меня заданно `assertContains` вот так:

```
$this->assertContains('success', $jsonToArray);
```

Но Contains может содержать 2 правилних значения.

- success
- Already added to watch later list

(если `contains` = значение1 "или" значение2, то `assert` верный )

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$this->assertTrue(in_array("success", $jsonToArray) || in_array("Already added to watch later list", $jsonToArray));
```

Comment: А почему по иностранному?

Comment: @Visman, извините, я просто сижу на обоих стеках, и что-то меня занесло:)

Comment: Failed asserting that an array has the subset Array &0 (
    0 => 'success'
    1 => 'Already added to watch later list'
).

Comment: Может я не понял вопрос, проясните еще раз пожалуйста у вам $jsonToArray имеет такой вид: ['success', 'Already added to watch later list', ...] или какой то другой?

Comment: $this->assertContains('success', $jsonToArray);  Но я хочу добавить еще и  это. 'Already added to watch later list' значение. То есть если в $jsonToArray значение равно  success "или" 'Already added to watch later list'. (логическое значение было "или" - "or").

Comment: @NarineGrigoryan, спасибо, поправил ответ, как-то подругому сделать в голову не приходит

Comment: Sergei Stralenia в любом случае, спасибо за помощь. )))